# Using Polymer Web Components and invoke password saving prompt

Tags: polymer

Polymer uses non-standard tags like paper-input etc. For example image a login form created with Polymer:

```
<paper-input id="email" floatingLabel inputValue="{{emailValue}}" label="Email"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="password" type="password" inputValue="{{passwordValue}}" label="Password"></paper-input>
<paper-button on-tap={{loginFunction}} label="Login"></paper-button>
```

How to utilize browser password storing capabilities and remember passwords entered into a Polymer form?

Comment: Everything is built from html elements, spiced with css and js. But all basic functionality is still there, and there shouldn't be a difference if you use them in a form just like you would use regular input elements. (It's not guaranteed that all standard attributes are always published and that a custom element doesn't explicitly manipulate them internally, css selectors don't cross the shadow boundary and some events)

Comment: This may not be answerable - each browser has its own approach to identifying username and password fields.

Comment: I'm guessing you use AJAX to submit that data, right? Browsers only store form data if you use the normal form submit process.

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you want, you can just get the password value by doing for example with JQuery `$('#password').val()`,  is this not what you want?

Comment: @JimmyKnoot I want a browser to prompt password saving functionality, so the user can leverage automatic password filling next time they visit a login form. This kind of functionality is also used by password managers of any sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `paper-input-decorator`, which simply wraps native inputs, e.g.:

```
  <paper-input-decorator label="Username" floatingLabel>
    <input is="core-input" name="username">
  </paper-input-decorator>

  <paper-input-decorator label="Password" floatingLabel>
    <input is="core-input" name="password" type="password">
  </paper-input-decorator>
```

Here's a JSBin of the above in case that's useful: http://jsbin.com/wumepu/2/edit?html,output

Comment: It is still not invoking password save in the browser nor Lastpass like in classic forms.

Comment: I don't think you can use this anymore. What would be the way to do it now?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace/complete the element paper-input with basic input on submit. Something like this in jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('<input type="text" name="fake-email-field">')
        .appendTo(this).val($('#email').val());
    $('<input type="password" name="fake-password-field">')
        .appendTo(this).val($('#password').val());
});
```

Comment: Isn't this backwards thinking. I know new solutions bring new problems but a component framework in 2014 promoted by Google should not promote hacking basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by the `autocomplete` attribute: In your case:

```
<paper-input 
  id="email" floatingLabel inputValue="{{emailValue}}" 
  label="Email" autocomplete="email">
</paper-input>
<paper-input id="password" type="password" inputValue="{{passwordValue}}" 
  label="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
</paper-input>
```

Instead of `current-password`, you can also specify `new-password` if this is a new account creation.